# How do you convert a string list into individual integers in python 3.4?

Tags: list, python-3.x, int

How would one go about converting a string list into individual integers that I can then add together or perform any other functions with?

Example:
    User inputs 123
    Program adds 1+2+3 and outputs the new integer of 6

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it's a little unformed. For instance, should it do 1+2+3 or 12+3? Look up "integer parsing" if you'd like to delve into this farther.

Answer (score 1):

you can just loop through a string like a list:

```
def sumOfDigits(userInt):
    sum = 0
    for i in str(userInt):
        sum += int(i)
    return sum
```

or generate a list from it for later use:

```
def listOfDigits(userInt):
    list = []
    for i in str(userInt):
        list.append(int(i))
    return list
```

Comment: How about if its a user provided integer? Would substituting '123' with the variable 'userInt' work or maybe 'userInt[0:]'?

Comment: yes, of course. you have to remember to convert it to string. i'll update the answer.